# How to insert auto-play option in my custom slider JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a slider code but the issue is I have to make it autoplay. This code actually compatible with my custom slider and I just want it to autoplay. I have tried some code shown below:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("contents-2");
    var slides2 = document.getElementsByClassName("contents-1");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].className = slides[i].className.replace(" cont-1", "");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++) {
        slides2[i].className = slides2[i].className.replace(" cont-2", "");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active-page", "");
    }
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active-page";
    slides[slideIndex - 1].className += " cont-1";
    slides2[slideIndex - 1].className += " cont-2";
    setTimeout(currentSlide, 2000);
}
```

Please help me with this code, the code above does not autoplay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could add an interval function to your code

```
setInterval(function(){ plusSlides(1); }, 3000);
```

Comment: the code is auto-playing but it shows only 2 slides instead I have 4

Comment: I used the below code:    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
    }, 4000);

Comment: you have that slideIndex = 1 in your code. Maybe it's that ?

Comment: the code above works perfectly but when I use navigation buttons it autoplay at a very high speed

Comment: 4000 means 4000 miliseconds = 4 seconds should work fine . You have a time out in your code maybe it is called again through the interval function. Could be better to add the autoplay there ?

Comment: Then what can be the value for slideIndex ?

Comment: sorry for that I would have to investigate your code more in depth. Actually I would separate the slide Index calculation and the showSlides routine.It's a bit confusing that way

Comment: pls see the below answer I just posted

Answer (score 0):

The new code I try is below:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("contents-2");
  var slides2 = document.getElementsByClassName("contents-1");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}   
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].className = slides[i].className.replace(" cont-1", "");  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides2.length; i++) {
slides2[i].className = slides2[i].className.replace(" cont-2", "");
  }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active-page", "");
  }
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active-page";
  slides[slideIndex-1].className += " cont-1";  
  slides2[slideIndex-1].className += " cont-2";
  setTimeout(function() {
        showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
    }, 4000);
}
```

the code above works perfectly but when I use navigation buttons it autoplay at a very high speed

Comment: your navigation buttons do reload the page or increase slideIndex ?

Comment: increase slideIndex i gues

Comment: so when you increase the slideIndex by your buttom the TimeOut is stll waiting for the update in the background which could be right after yours.You could do the slideIndex handling in a function which sets a time stamp. than check the timestamp before calling the autoplay

Comment: usually I do avoid as I said this type of code. I would try to have a clean function doing the slide animation and a clean function which does the slideIndexUpdate. and only one control. in your case it's a bit difficult to fix. Maybe it would be easier if you have an animation button that navigation could disable an animation. Sorry can't help more